Nonexistence of short integer program sequence which generates squares
Is there a way to show within an integer program with constant number of variables and constraints of length $poly(\log B)$ (say length $\leq10^{1000000}\log B$), it is not possible for a variable to take exactly all the square values up to a bound $B$?
If we have a sequence of such programs, as $B\rightarrow\infty$, we can get $\#P\subseteq FP/Poly$ and may be even $\#P\subseteq FP$. How can we be sure such a sequence of constant number of integer variable and constraint programs does not exist?
What joro shows below is a consequence and not a proof. Another consequence as mentioned is $\#P\subseteq FP/Poly$.
Is this related to non-existence of multiplication in Presburger arithmetic?
Posted here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54524/nonexistence-of-short-integer-program-sequence-which-generates-squares after a week as I have received no relevant answers other than someone here mentioning consequences whose violation is not known and may not be necessary to refute the existence of such programs. Moderators are also unwilling to remove such answers.

Maybe.  Need more details about your integer program.

Linear constraints and fixed number of integer variables and fixed number of constraints. Those are the details. You are defining a polyhedron in fixed number of variables and sides with one coordinate always a square.. I think this is not possible.

That is too vague of a description.  The conclusion will be true for some integer programs and false for others.

I'm also a little confused.  Here's one interpretation: given an integer program and a variable $X$, consider the set $S$ of values that $X$ takes among the feasible set.  (So, we're ignoring the objective function.) Then does there exist an integer program and a variable $X$ such that $S={z^2} ={0,1,4,9,16,...}$?  Is that what you're getting at?

https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/how-to-linearize-membership-in-a-finite-set

@BillBradley yes if we have $O(1)$ variables and constraints, how many squares can we cover?

I think you also want to require the variable to take all square values up to $B$, don't you? As things stand, it seems that the program x = 1 answers the question.

@PeterTaylor Thank you corrected.

If you can do this efficiently, you can factor integers efficiently.
Set $X-Y=N$.
If $X=u^2,Y=v^2$ then $(u^2-v^2)=(u-v)(u+v)=N$ will give the factorization of $N$.
To avoid the trivial solution, add the constraint
$ 1 < X < ((N+1)/2)^2$

The question was significantly rewritten than the original version.
I think the following is counterexample to the new question:
Consider the following decision problem:
Given two $n$ bit integers $a,b$, write IP program which returns
True iff $b=a^2$.
The slight modification of computing $c :=a\cdot b$ given $a,b$ with constant number of variables might be of practical importance
for multiplying large integers on conventional computer.

To spell out an important detail, if $M$ is a large odd number then taking $N=M$ doesn't work, because $u-v = 1$ gives a trivial solution, but taking $N=2M$ does work because $u-v=2$, $u+v = M$ runs into parity problems.

@PeterTaylor Indeed, there are some other constraints on X,Y to be added.

Sure.. factoring was the reason for the question...  it is obvious one can factor.  Indeed one can show #P is in FP if this is true.  So it seems there should be a proof for the O(1) case.

@Turbo I think unless you give bound on the solution, there is no way to describe such infinite set with linear constraints. But even with a bound, probably solving $X Y=N$ is more integer programming friendly.

@joro " there is no way to describe such infinite set..." why is that? That is the question here.

@Turbo I think if you can express the infinite sets with O(1) variables, you will factor all integers with O(1) variables. When you express multiplication in IP, you need something like log_2(N) variables and it depends on N.

That is not a proof. A proof should be able to quantify how many variables are needed etc.. Or at least be a proof by contradiction of some sort.. but it should reveal something.

I don't get it. How would we go from a program that answers whether a variable takes only square values to a program that answers whether two variables have some feasible square values (and possibly feasible non-square values as well)?

@ClaudeChaunier Besides answering that a value is square, I rely on actually computing the solution. Given a program which expresses exactly the set {m^2}, I use two copies of the IP program to find X=u^2=m_0^2 and Y=v^2=m_1^2 and then the solution.

@joro At this point you should remove your answer since even for the very first version of the question, your answer was not a proof but merely consequence of existence of such a program.
